# Symfony2 - Broken WebProfiler

Tags: php, symfony, profiler

Symfony 2.7 project has KnpMenuBundle and BraincraftedBootstrapBundle. Then I updated Symfony to 2.8.16v. Everything was OK, web profiler was working.

Then I removed the KnpMenuBundle and BraincraftedBootstrapBundle. Browser call profiler bar but doesnt display it anywhere. In /_profiler site I have strange sidemenu names. I dont know what's going wrong. How can I fix this?
Where to look for solutions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you remove those bundles? Did you clear your cache after that?

Comment: I removed bundles in composer, then update vendors, then clear cache and clear apc cache